# Como mostrar campos do tipo Radio Button no formulário usando Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

Criei um arquivo chamado const.py (aonde tenho as opções de choices que vou chamar no models) como segue abaixo:

**const.py**

```
FORENSIC_TRAFFIC_LIGHTING = (
    (u'1', u'Boa'),
    (u'2', u'Ruim'),
    (u'3', u'Ausente'),
)
```

**models.py**

```
class ForensicTraffic(models.Model):
    """
    Classe para modelagem 
    """
    lighting = models.CharField( 
    choices=const.FORENSIC_TRAFFIC_LIGHTING,
    max_length=1, 
    verbose_name='Iluminação'
)
```

Aqui está um pedaço do **form.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>{{traffic_form.lighting.label }}</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosLighting" id="optionsRadiosBoa" value="option1" checked>
            <label for="optionsRadiosBoa">Boa</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosLighting" id="optionsRadiosRuim" value="option2">
            <label for="optionsRadiosRuim">Ruim</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosLighting" id="optionsRadiosAusente" value="option3">
            <label for="optionsRadiosAusente">Ausente</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber como chamo essas opções no html! Por exemplo, quero que apareça com o tipo radioButton no meu formulario.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter que criar um Form para o seu Model, e nele indicar que o campo deve ter o widget *RadioSelect*:

**No forms.py**

```
class ForensicTrafficForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lighting = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=FORENSIC_TRAFFIC_LIGHTING))
    class Meta:
        model = ForensicTraffic
        fields = ['lighting']
```

**Na views.py:**

```
form = ForensicTrafficForm()
```

**No template:**

```
{% for radio in form.lighting %}
    <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
        {{ radio.choice_label }}
        <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Mais informações na documentação do Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect

Comment: Olá pessoal, agradeço a ajuda!! Tenham um bom dia :)!!

Answer (score 1):

## forms.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms
from models import ForensicTraffic
import const


class ForensicTrafficForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lighting = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(
        choices=const.FORENSIC_TRAFFIC_LIGHTING))
    class Meta:
        model = ForensicTraffic
        fields = ['lighting']
```

## views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from forms import ForensicTrafficForm


def forensic_traffic(request):
    form = ForensicTrafficForm()
    return render_to_response("forensic_traffic.html", locals(),
                                context_instance=RequestContext( request ))
```

Caso você quiser usar radiobuttons no admin também.

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import ForensicTraffic
from forms import ForensicTrafficForm


class ForensicTrafficAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ForensicTrafficForm

admin.site.register(ForensicTraffic, ForensicTrafficAdmin)
```